# How can I clean powder of dry paint on carpet?

Tags: paint, cleaning, carpet

I removed old paint from the wall with a steamer. Now I have a lot of this old paint in the form of powder or very small pieces all over my carpet.

It's OK because I plan to replace this carpet soon, however in the meantime I'd like to make it relatively clean.

Is there a way to remove this dry paint from the carpet without using a professional vacuum cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a shop vac, quite loud, but very high suction.  Use the smallest opening attachment and 'rake' the carpet.

If you don't own one, ask around.  If you decide to buy one, an 8 gallon wet/dry is a good intermediate size.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that tape works best if the paint is "stuck" a little bit to the carpet.  If you have a low weave carpet you could go strong and use duct tape.  For most carpets I have found packaging tape works best.